# I'm trying to find a specific word within a char array

Tags: c#, arrays, char

Using C# I'm trying to find a specific word within a char array. Also, I don't want the same letter used more than once i.e. the word is 'hello' and I'm trying to find it within a random array of letters, so if the letter 'l' is used out of the random array of letters, I don't want it to be used again. There should be another 'l' within the array of letters to be used as the second 'l' in "hello". Just trying to be precise. A simple answer would be very helpful. Thank you.

Here is my attempt so far.

```
public static char [] Note = "hello".ToCharArray();
public static char [] Newspaper = "ahrenlxlpoz".ToCharArray();

static void main(string[] args)
{
    Array.Sort(Note);
    Array.Sort(Newspaper);

    if(Newspaper.Contains<Note>)
    {
        Console.Write("It should display the letters of Note found within Newspaper");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In fact, a string is a char array. And the most "classic" way to do this would be:

```
string Note = "hello";
        char[] Newspaper = "ahrenlxlpoz".ToCharArray();
        string res = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < Note.Length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < Newspaper.Length; j++)
                if (Note[i] == Newspaper[j])
                {
                    res += Newspaper[j];
                    Newspaper[j] = ' ';
                    break;
                }
        //This prints the remaining characters in Newspaper. I avoid repeating chars.
        for (int i = 0; i < Newspaper.Length; i++ )
            Console.Write(Newspaper[i]+"\n");
        Console.Write("\n\n");

        if (Note.Equals(res)) Console.Write("Word found");
        else Console.Write("Word NOT found");
        Console.Read();
```

At the end, res will be "hello". Print res in the console. I added the `' '` to avoid repeated characters as someone said in the answer up. So at the end it will compare the result with the word and will tell you if it found the word in the string. Try changing Newspaper to this: `"ahrenlxlpaz"` and it will tell you the word is NOT found :)

Comment: I added something if you want to check it ^_^ 
ur welcome :3 @NepSyn14

Comment: 1) string is not a char array. It implements `IEnumerable<char>` and it has an indexer that gives access to chars, but that doesn't mean it's an array 2) Code is both unnecessarily complicated and slow `O(Note.Length * Newspaper.Length)`

Answer (score 3):

I assume by "contains" you mean Newspaper has enough number of letters from each letter to make up Note. For example, you need at least two l's to make up the word "hello". If so, you need to basically count the number of each letter in both strings, and make sure the number of each letter in Note is less than or equal to the number of that letter in Newspaper.

```
var dictNote = Note.GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
var dictNews = Newspaper.GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

bool contains = dictNote.All(x => 
    dictNews.ContainsKey(x.Key) && x.Value <= dictNews[x.Key]);
```

Comment: Thank you Eren. You are correct. I should try to have as many of the same letter as I need to make the word, in this case "hello" and not assume that one letter can be used multiple times.

Comment: Eren, can you tell me how I display the result of this please?

Comment: @NepSyn14 sure, but it's not clear to me how the result you want is any different from the word Note itself. You want "the letters of Note found within Newspaper", but isn't that all of the letters in Note anyway? (`Console.WriteLine(Note)`). Help me understand the result you need.

Comment: Hi Eren. I'm just trying to write a piece of code that will allow me to check if any letters I want to use, are within a char of random letters. I am just using 'hello' within Note as a starting point. I just want to be able to compare one char against another and see what they have in common and display the common letters. I hope that makes sense. I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make my questions clear but I'm still unfamiliar with some of the coding language and maybe I'm not wording it clearly enough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public static char[] Note = "hello".ToCharArray();
public static char[] Newspaper = "ahrenlxlpoz".ToCharArray();

foreach (char c in Note) //check each character of Note
{
    if (Newspaper.Contains(c))
    {
        Console.Write(c); //it will display hello
    }
}
```

Comment: @NepSyn14 note that this would still say "ahrenlxpoz" contains "hello" (even if there aren't enough "l"s).

Comment: Thank you Eren. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @NepSyn14 If that makes a difference, then I have an alternative answer for you. And you might want to update your question to indicate such a requirement.

Comment: Explain the line `string strNote = new string(Note); //change Note to string`, please. Do you want to take a clone and iterate through that, since you do not `foreach` through `Note` directly.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Thank you for mentioning. I didn't realize. Answer is updated